# How to add multiple labels in .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, label, kivy-language

My problem is that I want to add multiple labels without having to repeat so many lines of code. I have searched for solutions for a long time and all I see is simply writing a for loop in the python file instead of working on the .kv file. However, the location of the labels I want to add is inside a `GridLayout` inside a `scrollLayout` inside a `BoxLayout` and inside another `BoxLayout`. Is the only solution really to code all of that in my python file? Is there a better approach to this solution?

This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow, I am very new to all of this, please correct me if I haven't asked the question in a conventional or clear format. Thank you very much.

## python code

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('widgetq.kv')



class Win(Widget):
    pass



class WidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Win()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    WidgetApp().run()
```

## .kv file code

```
<Win>
    box1:box1
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 5
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    id:box1
                    orientation: 'tb-lr'
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    size_hint_y: None
                    row_default_height:180
                    spacing: 2
                    cols:1
                    Label:
                        background_color:(150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1)
                        text:"table"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: self.background_color
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
                    Label:
                        background_color:(150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1)
                        text:"table"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: self.background_color
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos

                    Label:
                        background_color:(150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1)
                        text:"table"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: self.background_color
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos

                    Label:
                        background_color:(150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1)
                        text:"table"
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: self.background_color
                            Rectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos



        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            Label:
                background_color:(94/255, 94/255, 94/255, 1)
                text:"tab"
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: self.background_color
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid writting the same code for every Label. As all your labels have the same style, you may create a custom Label class in your `.py` file:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label # Don't forget to import Label class

class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass
```

Then, in your `.kv` file customize that class:

```
<CustomLabel>:
    background_color:(150/255, 150/255, 150/255, 1)
    text:"table"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Now, you're able to call CustomLabel in your `.kv` file, instead of the whole code for every label. The example below produces the same result you already have.

```
<Win>
    box1:box1
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 5
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    id:box1 
                    orientation: 'tb-lr'
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    size_hint_y: None
                    row_default_height:180
                    spacing: 2
                    cols:1
                    CustomLabel:
                    CustomLabel:
                    CustomLabel:
                    CustomLabel:
```

As you can see you only have to call `CustomLabel:`.

However, if you pretend to add a lot of Labels, the best way is to use a `for` loop within your python file.

Comment: The helps a lot! Thank you very much.